# Декораторы для методов класса

Tags: python, django

В django есть замечательные штуки - generic.views, которые позволяют в несколько строк вывести список моделей, создавать и редактировать. Но, к сожалению, к ним не применимы обычные обертки, которые, например, проверяют залогинен ли пользователь.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^network/$', ComputerListView.as_view(), name='computer_list'),
```

views.py:

```
class ComputerListView(SiteCommonView, ListView):
    # класс SiteCommonView передан сюда, чтобы брать оттуда общий контекст для всех представлений
    model = Computer
    queryset = Computer.objects.all()
    #@auth_user_required
    #def as_view(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #    return super(ComputerListView, self).as_view(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        c = super(ComputerListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        c.update(self.get_context()) # это единственное для чего нужен SiteCommonView
        c['title'] = u'Компьютеры в сети'
        return c

# обертка
def auth_user_required(*args_, **kwargs_):
    def wrapper(func):
        def tmp(*args, **kwargs):
            request = args[0]
            if request.user:
                profile = get_user_profile(request)
                if profile: 
                    kwargs['profile'] = profile
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
            raise Http403()
        return tmp
    return wrapper
```

Итак, если раскомментируем

```
#def as_view(self, *args, **kwargs):
#    return super(ComputerListView, self).as_view(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Получаем ошибку: `TypeError at unbound method as_view() must be called with ComputerListView instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

Если раскомментируем

```
#@auth_user_required
```

получаем `TypeError at /network/ wrapper() got an unexpected keyword argument 'object_list'`

Как правильно писать обертки для методов класса в этом случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Decorating in URLconf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/#decorating-in-urlconf)

> The simplest way of decorating
> class-based views is to decorate the
> result of the `as_view()` method. The
> easiest place to do this is in the
> URLconf where you deploy your view:
>
> ```
> from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, permission_required
> from django.views.generic import TemplateView
>
> from .views import VoteView
>
> urlpatterns = patterns('',
>     (r'^about/', login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name="secret.html"))),
>     (r'^vote/', permission_required('polls.can_vote')(VoteView.as_view())),
> )
> ```

Кроме того, у вас не корректный декоратор. Единственным аргументом декоратора должен быть сам декорируемый метод. Т.е. должно быть примерно так:

```
from functools import wraps
from django.utils.decorators import available_attrs

def auth_user_required(func):
    @wraps(func, assigned=available_attrs(func))
    def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user:
            profile = get_user_profile(request)
            if profile: 
                kwargs['profile'] = profile
                return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        raise Http403()
    return wrapped
```

Так же можно попробовать сделать сл. образом:

```
class ComputerListView(SiteCommonView, ListView):

    # или SiteCommonView.dispatch, если он у вас определен там
    dispatch = auth_user_required(ListView.dispatch)

    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Для CBV вместо стандартных декораторов можно использовать миксины. Есть стандартные, такие как [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin), который отлично подойдёт для Вашего случая:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class ComputerListView(LoginRequiredMixin, SiteCommonView, ListView):
    model = Computer
    queryset = Computer.objects.all()
```

Среди сторонних, лучший вариант - django-braces. Ну и, конечно же, можно написать свои.